# SharePoint provider hosted app and form based authentication: the resource cannot be found

Tags: forms-authentication, provider-hosted-app, apps-development

I followed the following article, to change the web.config to use provider hosted apps in combination with fba.

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-on-Form-Based-Authentication-WebApplication-in-SharePoint-2013

I added the

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" />
```

But then it raises the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /login.aspx
```

Anybody any ideas?